# Cant access a div with either id or class in css style sheet

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add padding to the home-section div but am unable to do anything, neither can I access the div via id or class.
Please help

Here is the code for css:

```
body {
    margin: 0 ;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}


.header .navbar {
    padding: 0;
}

.home-section {
    background-color: red!important;
    padding: 250px 0px 200px;
}
```

Here is the div that I am trying to access index.php:

```
<body>
    <div class="container home-section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="home-content">
                    <h1>Awesome Product</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                    <a href="#">Buy For ₹150</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show minimal working example in SO Snippet? It should be working fine

Comment: Is your stylesheet placed in a separate directory? Try including the stylesheet in your HTML page within the ```<style></style>``` tag, if you'd want to keep it external, make sure specify the proper path to the '.css' file in your ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css/file">' ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the code you mentioned and it worked perfectly. It may you because you either have a Cache problem with the browser which happens usually with Chrome. You could check the result in an incognito page if such a thing happens though.

```html
<style>
body {
    margin: 0 ;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}


.header .navbar {
    padding: 0;
}

.home-section {
    background-color: red!important;
    padding: 250px 0px 200px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container home-section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="home-content">
                    <h1>Awesome Product</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                    <a href="#">Buy For ₹150</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure adding an answer to say it works OK without any explanation helps anyone.

Comment: Yeah, my bad I just restarted my server and it worked!

Comment: I'll edit it and explain a few. Thanks for mentioning. I'm kind of new ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    margin: 0 ;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}


.header .navbar {
    padding: 0;
}

.home-section {
    background-color: red!important;
    padding: 250px 0px 200px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container home-section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="home-content">
                    <h1>Awesome Product</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                    <a href="#">Buy For ₹150</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I ran your code and it work properly. May be some problem occurse in your browser, sometimes it happen. Run your code in incognito tab.